# Unable to edit with Elementor

Tags: errors, fatal-error

After installing Wordpress multisite configuration it is impossible to enter the Elementor edit environment, the following message shows: "the preview could not be loaded...", Unfortunately this [guide](https://elementor.com/help/how-to-fix-the-preview-could-not-be-loaded-error/) doesn't help.

Comment: In my experience, in order to use Elementor, At the setting, the wordpress URL and site URL have to be matched. Please check that first if they are identical. Thanks.

Comment: Since Wordpress multisite is installed the option you are speaking about is not available.